# How to evaluate something using stoke's

Tags: integration

Can someone show me how to evaluate this using stokes theorem.

$\int_{C}[ydx+y^{2}dy+(x+2z)dz]$ where C is the curve of intersection of the sphere $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=a^{2}$ and the plane $y+z=a$

Stokes theorem makes somewhere around 0 sense to me...

By a normal evaluation.
$z=2*[a^{2}-(x^{2}+y^{2})]^{\frac {1}{2}}$

we have $z=a-y$ Subbing $\to x^{2}+y^{2}+(a-y)^{2}=a^{2}$

$x^{2}+y^{2}+a^{2} +y^{2}-2ay =a^{2}$

$x^{2} +2(y-\frac {a}{2})^2 -\frac {a^{2}}{2} =0$

$(\frac{2^{1/2}x}{a})^{2} + (\frac{2y}{a}-1)^2 =1$ $u=\frac{2^{1/2}x}{a}$ $v=(\frac{2y}{a}-1)$ 
$u^{2}+v^{2}=1$ = $\pi*1^{2} *2$ * $Det|u,v|$

$Det|u,v|= \begin{bmatrix}
\frac {a}{2^{1/2}} & 0 \\
0 & \frac {a}{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Thus the answer should be $\frac{a^{2}\pi}{2^{1/2}}$

Can someone acquire this solution using stokes gibberish? thanks.

Edit:
i see no one wants to take a crack at this problem so i will give it a whirl i tried this before and i  got absolutely nowhere. If this part looks wrong or completely misguided it probably is i understand arclength parametrization but greens theorem, divergence and stokes are always a crap shoot for me.

firstly lets start with the theorem, $\int_{\partial S} F \cdot dx= \int \int_{S} (curl F) \cdot n dA$

$curl F = \begin{bmatrix}
i & j& k \\
d1 & d2 & d3 \\
F1 & F2 & F3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

$curl F =Det| \begin{bmatrix}
i & j& k \\
d1 & d2 & d3 \\
y & y^{2} & (x+2z) \\
\end{bmatrix}|$ =
$(0-0)i -(1-0)j+(0-1)k$

Clearly the norm of the surface pointed upward as viewed from above (n) is
$Curl F = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ -1   \\ -1  \\ \end{bmatrix} n = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1   \\ 1  \\ \end{bmatrix}$

$Curl F \cdot n= -2$

Now we have $\int \int_{S} -2 dA$ using above dA over S = $\frac{a^{2}\pi}{2^{3/2}}$
so we have the $\frac{a^{2}\pi}{2^{3/2}} * -2 = -\frac{a^{2}\pi}{2^{1/2}}$ not really sure why this one is negative, think id get any marks for this on a final?